# How can I count the nested replies?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a table structure like this.

```
--comments
id      article_id       comment_parent
1       9                0
2       0                1
3       0                1
4       0                2
5       0                4
```

Basically, the first comment is on the article_id, and replies to comments are on the comment_parent. The database above creates a nested comments such as this:

```
- Comment 1
    - Comment 2
        - Comment 4
            - Comment 5
    - Comment 3
```

The problem is, I couldn't find how to determine how many comments are on the article. Right now, article 9 has 5 comments.

I believe a recursive function would solve this issue, but my Eloquent experience is pretty basic.

How can I do something like this?

```
Article::find(9)->getAllCommentsAmount(); //5
```

Comment: Pretty strange DB design.

Comment: @delmadord Why is that?

Comment: Because it has a lot of redundance in the `article_id` and also some of the rows are dependend on one key and some on another. If you are using eloquent, consider using Polymorpthic Relations, since Comment can have Article or Comment as a parent.

Comment: @delmadord I wouldn't choose polymorphic relations for hierarchical data. Eloquent is not capable of handling it properly and/or efficiently.

Comment: @deczo Hello, you never fail to provide very clever answers/comments. Could you also give a link that supports your claim? For further reserach.

Comment: @delmadord not really, no. It's my experience after some (lot) time with Eloquent, and general issue with such DB schema for hierarchical data, like I stated in the comment to the lowereds' answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest adding the `article_id` to the child comments as well, if that is allowed. It will make it easier to count the comments for a certain article.

Comment: this is a simple but effective option

Comment: @lowerends I also thought about it and it was my B plan. It sounds very logical, but somehow feels like a bad practice to me. The main reason is, I don't think replies should care about the article at all, they should care about their parents and that's it.

Still, it is a very logical answer you provided. I'll pick it as the correct answer if nobody else provides a more elegant solution.

Comment: @Aristona Your db schema is simply not the best for hierarchical data. You cuold implement another desing, like nested sets, closure table etc - check this for examples: http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data  And this solution, although not normalized, is by far the best for your design. In the end, a comment is related to the article, because it exists only in its context, correct?

Comment: @deczo Okay, I'll read further about the database design. I'll pick this as the correct answer now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at implementing a Nested Set pattern in your database.

There is a fairly popular Laravel/Eloquent implementation available here:

https://github.com/etrepat/baum

Nested Sets are specifically designed for data that is heavily nested like yours, and allows you to quickly and easily (i.e. without heavy recursion) query your data.

Comment: I had a look at that package. Looks good but seems overkill for my needs.

Comment: I don't understand this "overkill" logic..  Nested Sets are the correct solution to the problem you are asking about (and I don't mean here on SO, I don't care about the points)..  On top of that, Baum even comes with an easy installation and migration process so adding it to your Laravel project is a snap.  You don't *have* to use all of it, just use what you need for now (the easy non-recursive counting of children, children who are easily aware of their parental chain, etc), and the rest will be there when you need it.  Good luck either way!